# XSLT 2.0 trimming text length of final HTML output

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

XSLT Fiddle here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Dh/2

In XSL 2.0 I receive a small set of nodes from an eXist-db Lucene search function that returns the original XML but wraps the search term in `<exist:match/>`. So I search on `tei:seg` and I get the following back (which I wrap on output in an extra element for later processing needs):

```
<doc>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/exist/apps/deheresi/doc/MS609-0454</url>
  <seg xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" type="dep_event" subtype="event" xml:id="MS609-0454-2" corresp="#MS609-0453-7">Item. Dixit<lb break="y" n="11"/>quod 
    <persName nymRef="#abbot_of_Saint_Papoul" role="npar">abbas de 
        <placeName nymRef="#Saint-Papoul_Aude">Sancto Papulo</placeName>
    </persName> ceperat 
    <persName nymRef="#heretics_not_named" role="par">duos hereticos</persName> et 
    <persName nymRef="#Arnald_Savauza_SML-AU" ana="#pFreeHer" role="par">Arnaldus de Savauza</persName> volebat manulevare dictos hereticos. Et rogavit 
    ipsum<lb break="y" n="12"/>testim et 
    <persName nymRef="#Arnald_Forner_SML-AU" ana="#pFreeHer" role="par">Arnaldum Fornier</persName> et 
    <persName nymRef="#Raimund_Forner_SML-AU" ana="#pFreeHer" role="par">Raimundum Fornier</persName>, fratres,  
    quod irent cum eo 
    ad abbatem de <placeName type="event_loc" nymRef="#Saint-Papoul_Abbey">Sancto<lb break="y" n="14"/>Papulo</placeName> 
    et manulevarent hereticos. Et dictus 
    <persName nymRef="#Arnald_Savauza_SML-AU" ana="#pFreeHer" role="ref">Arnaldus de Savauza</persName> 
    dixit quod dictus abbas promiserat ei quod redderet sibi dictos<lb break="y" n="15"/>
    hereticos pro mille <exist:match xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">solidis</exist:match> tholosanis. Et 
    <persName nymRef="#Bernard_Alzeu_SML-AU" ana="#pFreeHer" role="ref">Bernardus Alzeus</persName> et 
    <persName nymRef="#Ysarn_de_Gibel_SML-AU" ana="#pFreeHer" role="ref">Ysarnus de Gibel</persName> portabant illos denarios. 
    Sed non potuerunt dictos hereticos ma<lb break="n" n="16"/>nulevare. 
    <date type="event_date" when="1237">Et sunt anni VIIIor vel circa.</date>
  </seg>
</doc>
```

In XSLT I output this into HTML with some transformations. However, the output looks like this:

```
<td>Item. Dixit quod 
   abbas de 
   Sancto Papulo
   ceperat 
   duos hereticos et 
   Arnaldus de Savauza volebat manulevare dictos hereticos. Et rogavit 
   ipsum testim et 
   Arnaldum Fornier et 
   Raimundum Fornier, fratres,  
   quod irent cum eo 
   ad abbatem de Sancto Papulo 
   et manulevarent hereticos. Et dictus 
   Arnaldus de Savauza 
   dixit quod dictus abbas promiserat ei quod redderet sibi dictos 
   hereticos pro mille <span class="search-hit">
   <a href="http://localhost:8081/exist/apps/deheresi/doc/MS609-0454"> 
   solidis</a></span> tholosanis. Et 
   Bernardus Alzeus et 
   Ysarnus de Gibel portabant illos denarios. 
   Sed non potuerunt dictos hereticos manulevare. 
   Et sunt anni VIIIor vel circa.
</td>
```

But I'd like the final output to be shortened with ellipsis:

```
<td>...dictus abbas 
  promiserat ei quod redderet sibi dictos 
  hereticos pro mille <span class="search-hit"><a 
  href="http://localhost:8081/exist/apps/deheresi/doc/MS609-0454"> 
  solidis</a></span> tholosanis. Et 
  Bernardus Alzeus et 
  Ysarnus de Gibel portabant illos...
</td>
```

Where the text output on either side of the content of `<span class="search-hit"/>` is limited to `x` number of characters. (Further, if possible, applying `normalize-space()` to clean up problems with character spacing in the original document.)

I haven't found any ideas how to approach this within the current XSL  transformation, only in post-processing.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As the XML you have has the resulting text in lots of different elements and the current result is produced by pushing the XML through a couple of templates I am not sure how to fix that original XSLT, other than storing the current result in a variable and running it through a different mode that then normalizes and trims as required. I am not sure whether that is already the type of post-processing you do. As for the algorithm for trimming, do you have a single `span class="search-hit"` inside each `td`?

Comment: Yes, there is only ever one `span class="search-hit"` per output `td`.

Comment: I would also add that there wouldn't ever be any other elements inside the `td` - this is the final target output structure for search results.

Comment: I have tried to store the result of the original approach in a variable for the template matching `tei:seg` at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Dh/3, then you can push it through a different mode and do any normalizing and trimming and the two text nodes. The result there doesn't look pretty but I guess fine-tuning it with `replace` and/or `xsl:analyze-string` in the two templates for the text nodes should be easy if you know which algorithm you want for trimming or removing white space.

Comment: Assigning the variable inside the `seg` template is a really interesting solution, thanks. If you want to post this as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the contents of a `tei:seg` respectively `td` result you get from your existing code in a variable in

```
<xsl:template match="tei:seg">
    <xsl:variable name="search-hit">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$search-hit" mode="trim"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

and then you can push that content through a different mode that has templates for the text nodes to do the trimming:

```
<xsl:param name="trim-to" as="xs:integer" select="60"/>

<xsl:template match="text()[1]" mode="trim">
    <xsl:variable name="normalized" as="xs:string" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('...', substring($normalized, string-length($normalized) - $trim-to))"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[last()]" mode="trim">
    <xsl:variable name="normalized" as="xs:string" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($normalized, 1, $trim-to), '...')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class = 'search-hit']" mode="trim">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

The code doing the trimming/normalizing can be fine-tuned with using `replace` and/or `tokenize` and/or `xsl:analyze-string` in the text node templates but that is only possible if the algorithm needed for trimming is clear.

Fiddle is adjusted at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Dh/3.

Comment: In deploying this I realised there was a possibility that `<span class="search-hit">` could appear at the very beginning or end of `td`, and therefore the templates `text()[1]` and `text()[last()]` would be the same - this results in an `ambiguous rule match`. Is there a way to make these templates relative to text nodes before/after the span as opposed to absolute position? I tried to use following/preceding siblings but can't seem to find the right XPath formulation to hit the text nodes....

Comment: You could try `match="text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::span[@class = 'search-hit']]]"` for the `text()[1]` and `match="text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::span[@class = 'search-hit']]]"` for the `text()[last()]`. Not sure whether you need the predicate on the `span` if there is only that particular `span` at all created but the check with `following-sibling::node()[1][self::foo]` is the usual way to express there is a immediate `foo` sibling.